# Unit testing $modal with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, jasmine, angular-strap

I have an Angular app with a controller which displays an `Angular-Strap` modal window during a function call. It functions correctly in Chrome, but I am at a loss getting a valid unit test working.

**App module and the FooController:**

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["mgcrea.ngStrap"]);

app.controller("FooController", function($scope, $modal) {
    var fooModal = $modal({
        title: 'Foo',
        content:'Bar',
        show: false,
        html: true,
        backdrop: 'static',
        placement: 'center'});
    
    angular.extend($scope, {
        makeItFoo: function() {
            fooModal.show();
        }
    });
});
```

**Controller spec:**

```
describe('FooController', function () {
    var scope, controller, modal;

    beforeEach(module('app', function ($provide) {
        // Stub out $modal service
        $provide.value('$modal', function () {
            return {
                hide: function () { },
                show: function () { }
            };
        });
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $injector) {
        //set up a new scope and the controller for the test
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('FooController', {$scope: scope});
        modal = $injector.get('$modal');
    }));

    it('should show the modal', function () {
        var modalSpy = spyOn(modal(), 'show');
        
        scope.makeItFoo();
        
        expect(modalSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

[Here's a fiddle as well.](http://jsfiddle.net/dimmreaper/jwom7ns2/)

I expect my call to `makeItFoo()` to display the modal, but Jasmine fails the test with the error `Expected spy show to have been called`. I've also tried setting the `show` property of the modal to `true` and not calling `show()` separately, and I've tried other variants of stubbing the $modal service and injecting it directly into the controller, but it ends up with the same error.

I'm using AngularJS 1.2.14, Angular-Strap 2.0.0, and Jasmine 1.3.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of doing these. Create a mock object for `$modal` with show and hide methods and set your expectations on them.

```
describe('FooController', function () {
    var scope, controller, modal;

    beforeEach(module('app'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        //set up a new scope and the controller for the test
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        //Create spy object
        modal = jasmine.createSpyObj('modal', ['show', 'hide']);
        //provide modal as dependency to the controller.
        controller = $controller('FooController', {$scope: scope, $modal:modal});

    }));

    it('should show the modal', function () {

        scope.makeItFoo();

        expect(modal.show).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Comment: I was mid my answer when you posted it, you nailed it ;)

Comment: @maurycy haha it happens sometimes to me as well.. :)

Comment: @PSL, thanks! I was trying to understand the correct way to mock $modal, and this appears to be it. However, having updated my fiddle as you described, the test is still failing. Specifically, the error now reads `Argument 'FooController' is not a function, got undefined`; updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dimmreaper/jwom7ns2/3/).

Comment: @TheDIMMReaper I cannot access fiddle here, i use mocks every day, it must be some other issue. do you by any chance put it in a working jsbin or i will have to get back home to check the fiddle.

Comment: @TheDIMMReaper i got it, in my example i removed `beforeEach(module('app'))` add this and you should be good

Comment: @PSL - I noticed that, too, and tried adding it before I responded. But, that only changes the error to `object is not a function`.

Comment: @TheDIMMReaper which line is throwing object is not a function?

Comment: @PSL - I'm not sure how to interpret the line numbers in the Jasmine output in JSFiddle. I'm trying to replicate this (much) simplified example back into my IDE so that I can understand it better. I'll reply again once it is working there. In the meantime, [here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dimmreaper/jwom7ns2/4/) showing the latest error.

Comment: @TheDIMMReaper Here you go. I have not used this ng-strap, it seems   like it provides a constructor instead of instance. Here is how you can write test for this http://plnkr.co/edit/C10qMz?p=preview and for your version of jasmine http://jsfiddle.net/wovbzgr1/

Comment: @PSL - you hit the nail on the head - good thinking making a spy for the constructor function and a second spy object for its return. That's exactly what threw me off in the first place. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @PSL you have saved me a headache as I was able to inject the $modal dependency when i was testing directives that got compiled but because this does not get compiled the controller didn't recognise the injected dependency, so your approach to mocking the modal worked like a charm

Comment: How would this be managed if testing a directive? If there was on controller you could inject the mock into?

Comment: @user1005240 Use $provide to override $modal service with mock.

Answer (score 1):

The modal show is async. I updated your fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/jwom7ns2/1/.

Change the following portion:

```
it('should show the modal', function (done) {
    var modalSpy = spyOn(modal(), 'show');

    scope.makeItFoo();

    setTimeout(function() {
        expect(modalSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
        done();
    });

});
```

The timeout wrapper waits for the digest to happen when the modal show occurs.

Comment: I was about to comment before you revised your answer on why `scope.$apply`?. But i think this as well probably is an overkill IMHO, because OP already created a mock obj and then setting up spy. Instead all can be done at once by creating a mock object using jasmine. Also you really do not need to do `$injector.get('$modal')` instead `$modal` can be directly injected.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely seems like a viable solution. I'm going to give a shot first to the @PSL's method of mocking $modal, as I'd prefer not to deal with timing explicitly. If I have trouble there, I'll keep your solution in mind. Thanks!